# Logout React Reducer w/ History, State & Action Bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

Hey I've looked at a bunch of help files now and cant seem to get the issue solved. Most suggestions are using a different setup than I have. The main issue that the others dont have is the LOGOUT feature. Can you suggest another way to handle the LOGOUT?

Here is my index.js for "combine reducers":

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { LOGOUT_USER } from '../constants/index';

/* App Reducer Files */
import app from './app/reducer';
import accountData from './account/reducer';
import employeeData from './employee/reducer';
import locationData from './location/reducer';
import googleData from './google/reducer';
import requestData from './request/reducer';
import menuItemData from './menuItem/reducer';
import orderData from './order/reducer';

/* Public Reducer Files */
import valorData from './valor/reducer';

const appReducer = history => combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    app,
    accountData,
    employeeData,
    locationData,
    googleData,
    requestData,
    menuItemData,
    orderData,

    // Public
    valorData,
});

const rootReducer = history => (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT_USER) {
        state = undefined;
    }
    return appReducer(history, state, action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

And my store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import rootReducer from '../services';

import history from '../history';

const debugware = [];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    debugware.push(createLogger({
        collapsed: true,
    }));
}

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer(history),
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(
                routerMiddleware(history),
                thunkMiddleware,
                ...debugware,
            ),
        ),
    );

    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('../services', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../services/index').default;
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }

    return store;
}
```

This was working before I upgraded to a new router version. Again the main issue is the LOGOUT. If I just export appReducer it works just fine but doesnt logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW. The moment I post it I try one more thing...

```
const rootReducer = history => (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT_USER) {
        state = undefined;
    }
    return appReducer(history)(state, action);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you returning an undefined state? Instead, return

```
if (action.type === LOGOUT_USER) {
    return{ ...state, user: [] }
}
```

It basically returns and empty array as user.

Comment: This doesn't clear the reducer though... Where does user come from?

Comment: Do you mean... `return{ ...state, app: {} , accountData: {}, etc?}`

Comment: ...state means the rest of the data is going to be there (It is Iterating).

user: [] means you are simply providing a blank array as a user.

Comment: I don't have a user reducer... And if I'm just passing the state, whats the point. I need to clear the state or cache

Comment: This doesn't do anything, plus I would need to put every reducer there. undefined works just fine. Can you tell me why I should use this model instead?